# Is $a \le b$ a true statement if $a < b$?

Tags: logic, relations, order-theory

My question is:

Is $a \le b$ true if $a < b$?

For instance: Is $3 \le 4$ a true statement?
I think yes, because $a \le b$ is defined as $a < b\vee a = b$ and this should be true, even if $a = b$ is always false, right?

Thank you very much for your help!
FunkyPeanut

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: Looks correct to me. But vice versa isn't correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for that fast answer :) @Module yes, I am aware of that but thanks for that, too.

Comment: "If $a$ is less than $b$, is $a$ less than or equal to $b$?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases $a<b$ is *defined* as saying that $a\le b$ is true **and** $a\neq b$ is true. Thus if $a<b$ is true, so is $a\le b$.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is !!

> If $a < b$, then surely $a ≤ b$,

as $≤$ implies less than **or** equal to. If any one of the conditions, i.e. $<$ or $=$, is true then $a ≤ b$ is true. Therefore $a ≤ b$ will always be true, if $a<b$.